# How do I provide a clean implementation of a Seam

Tags: unit-testing, moq

In many cases, I write code with protected virtual methods to provide seams (to assist in unit testing):

```
public class TemporaryStorage     
{
    public TemporaryStorage()
    {
     this.RootPath = Path.Combine(this.GetEnvironmentPath, Path.GetRandomFileName());
    }
    public string RootPath { get; private set; }
    protected virtual string GetEnvironmentPath
    {
         get { return LocalStorage.GetEnvironmentPath(); }
    }
}
```

Then, in the test suite, I will derive from this class and provide a custom implementation for GetEnvironmentPath().

Instead of creating the derived class within the test suite, is a better approach available?  Can I use MOQ to accomplish the same results (providing a substitue implementation for GetEnvironmentPath)?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to mock your classes under test is using interfaces. When your class under test implements a certain interface, then you can simply write a mock using MOQ like this:

Let's say, you've got an interface like that:

```
private interface IMyInterface
{
    string MyMethod(int value);

    int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can configure a mock like this:

```
var mockedObject = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
mockedObject.Setup(x => x.MyMethod(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(value => value.ToString());
mockedObject.SetupGet(x => x.MyProperty).Returns(42);
```

You can access your mocked object in your unit test in this way:

```
DoSomething(mockedObject.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rhino Mocks is one of the mocking frameworks that supports this.

If you have a look at the following info you see an [example](http://ayende.com/Wiki/%28S%28gvtu2q45soph42vfyhig2j55%29%29/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx).

To make sure that the protected method can be unit tested you can change the signature to internal protected instead of protected. If you then use the InternalsVisibleTo in your AssemblyInfo.cs you can make your internals visible to the unit testing project (see [How to make a "protected" method available for "partial" mocking using RhinoMocks](http://geekswithblogs.net/MattRobertsBlog/archive/2008/12/16/how-to-make-a-quotprotectedquot-method-available-for-quotpartialquot-mocking-and-again.aspx)).